# DB Query not working in Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, mysql

I am working on a plugin. And I want to create a table via the plugin. So I am trying execute following SQL Query.

```
global $wpdb;
$createSQL              =   "
CREATE TABLE `". $wpdb->prefix ."_book_ratings` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rating` float(3.1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB" . $wpdb->get_charset_collate() . " AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
";

require( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $createSQL );
```

When I deactivate the plugin and when re-activating the plugin I am getting following error.

`The plugin generated 464 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.`

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: “headers already sent” messages generally display when you not start or end PHP tag in file. also remove white space before start PHP tag or Ending PHP tag.

Comment: Do you have error logging enabled? What is this additional output you get?

Comment: Sorry I haven't enabled error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the SQL query in `$createSQL`,

1. `ENGINE=InnoDB" . $wpdb->get_charset_collate() . " AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` yields to:

   > Error in query (1286): Unknown storage engine 'InnoDBDEFAULT'

   To fix it, add a space between the `ENGINE=InnoDB` (the storage engine) and `" . $wpdb->get_charset_collate()` (the charset).
2. You have defined the column `id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but the column is not a key, and that yields to the following error:

   > Error in query (1075): Incorrect table definition; there can be only
   >   one auto column and it must be defined as a key

   To fix it, define the column `id` as a key using either `PRIMARY KEY (id)` or `KEY(id)`.

So, here's the fixed code (or SQL query), tried and tested working on WordPress 4.9.8:

```
$createSQL              =   "
CREATE TABLE `". $wpdb->prefix ."_book_ratings` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rating` float(3.1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB " . $wpdb->get_charset_collate() . " AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
";
```

If that doesn't work for you, follow the guides [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table), such as use *two* spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.